# Box of maximum volume inscribed in a hemisphere of radius $r$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, solution-verification, maxima-minima

I have solved the following problem and I would appreciate feedback on my solution, thanks.

> A rectangular box is inscribed in a hemisphere of radius r.
> Find the dimensions of the box of maximum volume.

What I have done:

Considering the box with the center of its base at the origin, we have the volume $V(x,y,z)=2x\cdot 2y\cdot z=4xyz=4xy\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2},\ x,y,z>0$

$$Df(x,y)=4\begin{bmatrix}y\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}-\frac{x^2y}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}} & x\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}-\frac{xy^2}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}y\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}\right)=0\\ x\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}\left(1-\frac{y^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}\right)=0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}y=0 &\text{ or } x^2+2y^2=r^2\\ x=0 &\text{ or } 2x^2+y^2=r^2\end{cases}.$$
We have to discard the solutions $x=0$ or $y=0$ since in that case we wouldn't have a box.

So it must be $x^2+2y^2=r^2$ and $2x^2+y^2=r^2$ thus $x^2+2y^2=2x^2+y^2\Leftrightarrow x^2-y^2=0\Leftrightarrow x=y\Rightarrow z=\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2x^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2y^2}.$

Since $x^2+y^2=3x^2=r^2$ we have $\fbox{$x=\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}$}$,  similarly $x^2+2y^2=3y^2=r^2$ so $\fbox{$y=\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}$}$ and finally $\fbox{$z=$}\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2x^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2y^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}=\sqrt{r^2-\frac{2r^2}{3}}=\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{3}}=\fbox{$\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}$}.$

Thus the box of maximum volume inscribed in a hemisphere of radius $r$ is a box with a square basis with side length $2x=2y=\frac{2r}{\sqrt{3}}$ and height $z=\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}$ hence with volume $V=2x\cdot 2y\cdot z=\frac{4r^3}{\sqrt{27}}.$

Comment: Naively it would seem there are more than one inscribed box which have a square base.

Comment: @coffeemath thank you for your interest in my question; I have added the specification "the box of maximum volume is the one with a square basis and a height of $z=\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2x^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2y^2}.$". Do you think it is correct (and complete) now?

Comment: lorenzo: No I think the max volume is a *specific* box which fits your description. I agree you have shown that, among "axis alligned" boxes the max must occur at one with a square base. But only a specific one of that type will give the actual max volume. For example a box which is of dimensions $1/n \times 1/n \times (r^2-2/n^2)$ for very large $n$ would fit your description but have very small volume.

Comment: I forgot a squareroot symbol over the third dimension $(r^2-2/n^2)$ in my comment above.

Comment: @coffeemath I see; I have modified my solution accordingly, thank you very much. If you would write your comments as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: You started with the statement "volume $V(x,y,z)=2x\cdot 2y\cdot z=4xyz$", but you used $V=xyz$ in your final statement.

Comment: lorenzo... Since my comment only pointed out your answer couldn't be correct, I don't think it should be turned into an answer.

Comment: @coffeemath they made me realize I could have (and should have) found the dimensions of the box which allowed me to finish the problem, but I understand your point of view.

Comment: lorenzo: Note that your answer now is the box has dimensions $2x \times 2x \times x.$ Thus as expected its shape is that of half of a cube which has been cut by the plane forming the lower boundary of the hemisphere. So when doubled it gives the expected cube inside a sphere.

Comment: @nickgard It should be correct now, thanks.